# best matrix full of same number

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra, sage

I would like to create a n x n matrix with n being a large number, what is the fastest way to do this in sage ?

I would like a matrix like for example `n = 3 == [(3,3,3)(3,3,3),(3,3,3)]`

I currently do this with 
`ones_matrix(n) * somenumber`

However this takes a while with a big n, is there a faster way to do this in sage?

Thx for helping

Comment: Maybe the trick is to not materialize (e.g. fully create) the matrix?  What are you planning to do with it once it's created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `numpy.full()` function like so:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.full((3, 3), 3)
>>> arr
[[3 3 3]
 [3 3 3]
 [3 3 3]]
>>> arr2 = np.full((3, 3), 7)
>>> arr2
[[7 7 7]
 [7 7 7]
 [7 7 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A  shortcut way would be:

```
n=int(input())
tup=tuple((n,))*n
#gives (n,n,n,...…,n) n times

ar=list((tup,)*n)
#would give ar=[(n,n,.....,n),(n,n,n,.....,n),...…..(n,n,n,...…,n)]
```

or doing in a single stroke:
`ar=list((tuple((n,))*n,)*n)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with Sage matrices, you can do this:

```
sage: M = MatrixSpace(ZZ, 10000, 10000)
sage: a = M.matrix([3]*10000*10000)
```

On my computer, this takes about 6 seconds, the same time as `ones_matrix(10000)`, faster than `3 * ones_matrix(10000)`. Not nearly as fast as the `numpy` solution, but then the result is a Sage matrix. Note that if you want to work with noninteger entries, you should change the `ZZ` to the appropriate ring.